# scan python helper in elasticsearch with slice

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have the following code:

```
client = Elasticsearch(hosts=['host'], port=9200)
scan_arguments = {'query': {'slice': {'max': 1, 'id': 0}}, 'preference': '_shards:0', 'index': u'my_index'}

for hit in scan(client, **scan_args):
    # do something with hit
```

and I get the following error

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception', u'[slice] failed to parse field [max]')
```

How should the slice parameter be passed in the scan function?

Comment: Take a look to the documentaion: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-scroll.html#sliced-scroll The slice param indicates to split the answer in n parts. But you need also a correct query. You haven't post any query. Maybe you would use a match_all query?

Comment: tried the following `{'query': {'query': {'match': {'http_user': 'user'}}, 'slice': {'max': 1, 'id': 0}}, 'doc_type': '_doc', 'preference': '_shards:0', 'index': u'my_index'}` but the same exception. But a query is optional parameter.

Answer (score 3):

"max" needs to be >1 in my experience. I saw the same error before when using "max":1.

Comment: I found that if I needed 10 slices, I needed to give max 11.

Answer (score 0):

The raw error from the HTTP API says `max` must be greater than 1.

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason": "[3:20] [slice] failed to parse field [max]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
    "reason": "[3:20] [slice] failed to parse field [max]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "max must be greater than 1"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```